# Is there a way to play multiple music files from a windows phone alarm?

Tags: windows-phone-8, alarm

I want to set an alarm and have it play 3 or 4 music files when the alarm goes off.

Something like:

```
var alarm = new Microsoft.Phone.Scheduler.Alarm("Test Alarm");
        alarm.Content = "My Test Alarm";
        alarm.BeginTime = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(10);
        alarm.ExpirationTime = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(15);
        alarm.RecurrenceType = RecurrenceInterval.None;
        alarm.Sound = new Uri("myFirstSong.mp3", UriKind.Relative);
```

And then once myFirstSong.mp3 has finished, it will go on to play mySecondSong.mp3 and myThirdSong.mp3.

I was hoping there might be some kind of event when the alarm goes off that I could hook up to, but there doesn't seem to be.

Another alternative I was wondering about is how the alarm plays the music file - for example does it use BackgroundAudioPlayer, which I could hook into an event of?

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Maybe being able to start another app or navigate to a different page which would run the code I need would work... Is it possible for an alarm to go off and automatically navigate to a different app/page?

Comment: You can create a reminder and when an user click on alarm navigate to a page. Don't forget remiver.uri = new Page